# Reload page whenever url changes wix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, velo

I am trying to load some external scripts inside wix which requires page to load so that data can be fetched

I am using this code for all pages

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
wixLocation.onChange( (location) => {
 wixLocation.to(wixLocation.url);
} );
```

It works well if i move between url like from example.com/product/1 to example.com/product/2

But not working when i am moving from different path like from example.com to example.com/product which stop my external script to load on product page

Thanks

Comment: Maybe that example.com root doesn't have `wixLocation` defined/used?

Comment: Its defined its just working if 1st path after first / is same else it is not working anywhere

Comment: I tried to console when onChange triggers it only triger if first path in url is same